# MacOS media keys not activating navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler(...)

Tags: javascript

In our program we set up our media key listeners with simple call to the `setActionHandler` function: `navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', playCb)`. This works cross-browser on Windows, but with MacOS it doesn't work on any browser I've tried-- Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. Pressing F8 simply does nothing. I tried using the media keys on YouTube and they work just fine MacOS, across all three browsers. This problem exists across users so it's not localized. Furthermore, if YouTube is up in a different tab than our application, YouTube still responds to the Pause/Play button" Any ideas?